# Odd white stripe at the right of a table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app with nav controller, I have a weird white line appearing at the right of my table view, when my table view cells are customed. They're loaded from a NIB. This NIB has the right dimensions (320 width), and the image for the table view cell background is 320 too (640 for retina @2x).

I have double checked all my parameters in the custom cell nib, in the table view nib etc. I don't understand.

Here is a screenshot from the first cells (empty content) :
http://img38.imageshack.us/i/whitestripe.png/

It happens in the simulator and on device, retina display or normal display...

Anybody have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: I have only worked with custom cells a small amount, but could it be a space from a confused or left over accessory setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom view XIB file, check that the x and y of the outermost containing view are zero, and not some negative value that would offset the view.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it all again, everything seems to be OK.

So I just created my custom cell programatically, and now everything works well, no more white line at the right.

Thanks everybody !!